# Component array not shown in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native, and I wonder why my code isn't working.
I know thorugh console.logging that my output array is full with the correct data, but for some reason in the return when I try to write out the output it doesnt seem to writing anything to the mobile screen. I wonder why that might be.

```js
const ChampionScreen = () => {
    const [champions, setChampions] = useState([]);
    var output = [];
    useEffect(() => {
      AxiosService.getChampions()
      .then(data => {
        setChampions(data);
        var champarr =[];
        Object.keys(champions).forEach(function(key){
          champarr.push(champions[key]);
        }) 
        for(let i = 0; i < champarr.length;i++){
          let champion = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(champarr[i]));
          var tempItem = (
            <View key={i}>
              <Text>{champion.name}</Text>
            </View>
          );
          output[i] = (tempItem);
        }
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
    },[])

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
          {output}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Comment: `output` is a local variable and is reset on every render cycle. `useEffect` fills `output`, but on the rerender, the useEffect is not executed anymore and the array remains empty. Try to build the `<View>` using `champions` outside the `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not define `output` as a state variable and it will not trigger a render that way. after that, when you are mapping the `data` object with `Object.keys` method, you are kind of going with luck because **the state updates are asyncronous**, so you should not set the state and immediately use the state, use the data you already fetched. here it is:

```js
const ChampionScreen = () => {
    const [champions, setChampions] = useState([]);
    const [output, setOutput] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      AxiosService.getChampions()
      .then(data => {
        setChampions(data);
        var champarr = [];
        let axiosOutput = [];
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
          champarr.push(data[key]);
        }) 
        for(let i = 0; i < champarr.length;i++){
          let champion = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(champarr[i]));
          var tempItem = (
            <View key={i}>
              <Text>{champion.name}</Text>
            </View>
          );
          axiosOutput.push(tempItem);
        }
        setOutput(axiosOutput)
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
    },[])

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
          {output}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
}
```